# How to send c2dm message from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, push-notification, android-c2dm, rhomobile

### EDIT 3

I use RhoMobile to get device_token, which I am getting to server

```
def register_device
    @person = Person.find(:first)
    unless System.get_property('is_emulator')
     url = "#{@base}/users/#{@person.remote_id}/register_device?os=#{System.get_property('platform')}&device_token=#{System.get_property('device_id')}"
     Rho::AsyncHttp.get(
        :url => url,
        :headers => {'User-Agent' => Rho::RhoConfig.user_agent}
      )
    end
    finish_and_go_to_venue
  end
```

### EDIT 2

Have device_token but keep getting `Error=NotRegistered`

### EDIT

OK, so first mistake was using the wrong device ID.  Now working, but phone not alerting with message.

### ORIGINAL

First time user of sending android Push messages from rails server.

Using https://github.com/sghael/speedy_c2dm

I registered with google and received white list email.

trying test.rb below, but nothing gets sent to phone.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup(:default, :development)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'speedy_c2dm'


TEST_EMAIL = "my_push_email@gmail.com"
TEST_PASSWORD = "MY_PASSWORD"
TEST_REGISTRATION_ID = "DEVICE_TOKEN_RECEIVED_FROM_PHONE"

speedyC2DM = SpeedyC2DM::API.new(TEST_EMAIL, TEST_PASSWORD)

options = {
  :registration_id => TEST_REGISTRATION_ID,
  :message => "Hi!",
  :extra_data => 42,
  :collapse_key => "some-collapse-key"
}


response = speedyC2DM.send_notification(options)
```

Comment: What about android code?

Comment: I get token from rhomobile function.  Updated question with code

Comment: Got it working.  was wrong setup on phone.

Comment: How did you fix it on the phone? I'm also trying to send push notif's to a rhodes android app. thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a Controller named Push and inside the controller you need to have the following:

```
require 'rho/rhocontroller'
require 'helpers/browser_helper'

class PushController < Rho::RhoController
  include BrowserHelper

  def push_callback

    Alert.show_popup @params['message'] #this will show you a popup with your push message
    puts "push_callback : #{@params}" #you'll see what you are receiving with this
    "rho_push"  #to run rhodes push command processing (for alerts, sounds, etc…)
  end


end
```

you need to set your application to call this by adding the following line to your **application.rb**

```
System.set_push_notification "/app/Push/push_callback", ''
```

Also, did you configure your build.yml correctly?

```
android:
  push:
    notification: always
    sender: your-sender-email@gmail.com
capabilities:
  - push
  - vibrate
```

At least with my app, I need to have the application running in order to get the message.

Comment: instead of another controller just added to controller.rb under the Settings folder.